# Building Chrome Extensions with Vuejs and Vuecli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli

I'm currently building a Chrome Extension with a [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) powered frontend. This worked pretty great using [`vuecli`](https://cli.vuejs.org/). Up until the point at which the app started using the `Webextension`-API. Normal websites do not have access to this API; registered Extensions do.

So what's a good setup for developing a `vuejs`-Extension with the power of using `vuecli` (which supports webpack tooling)? What setup allows to test the application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend using [`vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension`](https://github.com/adambullmer/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension). Note that while the README indicates Vue CLI 3.x support, it also works with Vue CLI 4.x (tested with 4.3.1).

It supports several features that will save you a bunch of time, including live-reload, and bundling for Chrome and Firefox (and other browsers).

To install it in a Vue CLI project, just run: `vue add browser-extension`.

Answer (score 1):

After some contemplating, I came across the [`vue-cli-service`-binary](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html). This binary allows to `watch` a project and rebuild the app as required. By default, `vuecli` will output files to `dist`, which is the directory in which I placed `manifest.json`, `contentScript.js` and `backgroundScript.js` files. The following command will then rebuild the app as needed, allowing for *almost* hot-reloading (opening and closing the popup). Build times are reasonably quick for a small app (~200ms).

```sh
vue-cli-service build --watch --no-clean
```

Lastly, you might have to disable `eslint` on save (see [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-eslint#configuration)), as it throws errors about `chrome` not being found. Then I load the unpacked extension into a clean Chrome session and start testing it using the developer tools. Unfortunately, I have not yet gotten `Vue Devtools` working with the extension.

It works for me: I can develop `vuejs`-powered Chrome extensions in a reasonabale way. I am still wondering if anybody has any better workflows or ideas for improvement?

EDIT:
@tony19's answer is the preferred way.